# Android HTML5 Video offline caching

Tags: android, html, html5-video

I've an android app already developed.

The android app is essentially a wrapper around a HTML5 web app.

We use HTML5 offline caching to provide the ability to play when disconnected from the internet.

Chrome/Firefox on the desktop will cache the video and images however Android devices 
appear to selectively ignore video in the cache manifest which prevents the video from 
being stored locally on the device.

It's understandable that Android would ignore caching video to keep the storage use to a 
minimum on mobile devices but we need a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this question after I stumbled across an answer - so thought i'd help out!

I'm trying to do a similar thing for Android/iOS, and as far as I know the appcache is very restricted on mobile devices (Android varies depending on available disk space & browser used, and on iOS I haven't had luck getting above 50mb).

I recommend using a framework such as [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) or [Chrome Apps](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps) - they offer other forms of local storage by communicating with the device's native file APIs.